# Dynamic allocation of memory (Array of pointers)

Tags: c++, memory-management

is there a memory leak in this operator overloading ?

My thinking is below the code.. (MotorVehicle is a class with no allocation)

```
class myClass{    
private:
    MotorVehicle **vehicle;
    int vehNo;
public:

myClass() : vehicle(), vehNo(0){ } // vehicle() -> NULL

    ~myClass()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < vehNo; i++)
            delete vehicle[i];
    }
    .
    .
    .
    myClass &operator+=(MotorVehicle *veh)
    {
        MotorVehicle **temp = new MotorVehicle*[vehNo + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < vehNo; i++)
            temp[i] = vehicle[i];
        temp[vehNo] = veh;
        //for(int i = 0; i < vehNo; i++)
          //  delete vehicle[i];
        vehNo++;
        vehicle = new MotorVehicle*[vehNo];
        for(int i = 0; i < vehNo; i++)
            vehicle[i] = temp[i];

        return *this;
    }
};
```

I have array of pointers of type MotorVehicle (**tmp) for which I have allocated memory and set every single one of them to point to what a vehicle is pointing to + last one to point to what veh was pointing to. Since I set them to point to what vehicle was pointing I wont lost the data somewhere and can deallocate them in the future. Then I allocated memory for vehicle again to return them to point to +1 object. However I'm allocating memory two times and both contain the location of same thing, so If i delete one of them then the other won't have anything in it (will hang somewhere).. But at the end the memory will get deleted with the destructor ?
Am I thinking right? How to get around allocating memory 2 times for the same thing?

P.s yeah manually :# (Any materials which might help me in any way would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: Why not simply use `std::vector`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's because of the lectures.. :/

Comment: If you want to do things manually, I suggest creating a true dynamic array class instead of a `MotorVehicle` class.  If not, you're just going to write the same code over and over again for this class, that class, another class -- just create a vector class, and use it in all of your future assignments.  Then your `MotorVehichle` class would look as simple as if you actually used `std::vector`.

Comment: You have a memory leak. `temp` is never deallocated. But It would easier if you use `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're leaking `temp`.

A better try:

```
myClass &operator+=(MotorVehicle *veh)
{
    MotorVehicle **temp = new MotorVehicle*[vehNo + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < vehNo; i++)
        temp[i] = vehicle[i];
    temp[vehNo] = veh;
    vehNo++;
    delete[] vehicle;
    vehicle = temp;

    return *this;
}
```

An even better solution: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: I think that this would work only for array of objects of type MotorVehicle.. delete [] vehicle; won't delete anything since vehicle is pointing to pointers ?

Comment: It deletes the storage for the array of pointers.  You don't want to delete the `MotorVehicle`s themselves, since you just copied their pointers over.

Comment: So `vehicle = temp;` would do the job of making vehicle point to whatever pointers temp was pointing to ?

Comment: Oh all you wanna say is to free the allocated space but not the thing its pointing to, so by passing the address to vehicle -> it will be in charge.. Thankss !!